# Looking for this SMD component (B2 RG)

Tags: diodes, identification, surface-mount

Looking for this SMD component (diode?) which is broken. It has name "B2 RG".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The markings match with a [Vishay RS07G](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2206211730_Vishay-Intertech-RS07J-GS08_C968644.pdf) diode.

[image]

I could find a picture of this exact diode, but of the RS07J that shows a similar marking style. Please note, however, that there are [quite a few diodes](https://smd.yooneed.one/code5247.html) with a `RG` marking, so make sure I guessed the package correctly as SMF.

[image]

(Source: [lcsc.com](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Diodes-Fast-Recovery-Rectifiers_Vishay-Intertech-RS07J-GS08_C968644.html))